# Modify U/K Live CD

Tags: live-cd

I'd Like Modify Kubuntu 12.04 Live CD/USB (Chance name system Kubuntu for KWES DOS)
chance Image ISO Linux & Splash image(KDE Loging in) for a Image
plymouth etc. etc.
tell me how!
please

Answer (score 0):

Check out a tool called **Remastersys**. It builds live CDs off an existing installation
.

Remastersys is a tool that can be used to do 2 things with an existing Debian,  Ubuntu or derivative installation.

It can make a full system backup including personal data to a live cd or dvd that you can use anywhere and install. It can make a distributable copy you can share with friends.  This will not have any of your personal user data in it.

[www.remastersys.com](http://www.remastersys.com/)